# Как присвоить значинию аргумента по умолчанию значение переменной?

Tags: php, silex

Здравствуйте! Есть код:

```
function($somevar_1, $somevar_2) {
    //code...
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы если параметр `$somevar_2` не был передан, то ему присваивалось значение по умолчанию. В мануале написано, что можно сделать так:

```
function($somevar_1, $somevar_2 = 'string') {
    //code...
}
```

Но проблема в том, что мне нужно установить значение по умолчанию, как другая переменная. Пробовал делать так:

```
$arg = 'string';
function($somevar_1, $somevar_2 = $arg) {
    //code...
}
```

Такой код не работает. Выдаёт ошибку:
`Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Что делать?

Comment: установить значение по умолчанию,  например, `null`, проверить в коде, и если `null`, то заменить назначение первого аргумента.

Comment: вы не думайте, что значения по умолчанию применяются на этапе выполнения скрипта. это синтаксический сахар, так сказать. если у вас `a($b, $c = null)` и вы напишите `a(0)` то это только для вас красиво, реальный вызов будет `a(0, null)` то есть на этапе работы парсера, или чего там еще.  и так в принципе в любом языке, наверное.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал, как вы сказали - установил значение по умолчанию `null`, всё получилось